# Is it possible to declare a const of an array in BOTH Delphi and FreePascal without having the elements be constants?

Tags: delphi, arrays, constants, freepascal

A long time ago I remember I could do this in Turbo Pascal 7.

Maybe I'm wrong and it's something I need to clarify, but is it possible to declare an array of strings as a constant?

If not what's the option/workaround.

What I have now is:

```
type
  TStates = (sOne, sTwo, sThree);
var
  TArrayOfString: array [sOne..sThree] of string = 
     ('State one', 'State two', 'State three');
```

but would want to replace that var with a const.

Thanks

**Edit 1**: Added some more code to clarify my question.

Comment: Works for me with const as well - maybe you need to add some more information?

Comment: You shouldn't call it "TArrayOfString", because it's not a TYPE. It's a const/var!

Comment: I've read over your question a few times and I am not sure I understand exactly what you are asking.  If not, then please let me know.

Comment: @Gustavo: Why don't you just replace var with const, and are happy?

Comment: @mghie And would that work for both Delphi and FreePascal?

Comment: @Gustavo: I don't know. But if that's your point, then you should remove the delphi tag and also remove the word from the question title - there is no problem whatsoever with your code when using Delphi.

Comment: @mghie: My intention is to have it working on both, hence the tags for Delphi AND FreePascal. I'll probably have to get some {$IFDEF}'s then.

Comment: -1 for musing about what a solution might be when it's really the solution. Try it out before you ask next time. (You DO have a copy of Free Pascal, don't you?) And your edit to clarify the question didn't really change anything -- the array index type is irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just replacing **var** with **const** is perfectly legal:

```
const
  TArrayOfString: array [1..3] of string =
     ('String one', 'String two', 'String three');
```

I am curious why your identifier name starts with a **T** though.  Were you trying to define a type like this:

```
type
  TArrayOfString = array [1..3] of string;
const
  MyArrayOfString: TArrayOfString =
     ('String one', 'String two', 'String three');
```

You cannot have a variable length array (AFAIK) as a const, nor can you have it of an undefined type.

This is with Delphi 2009.  YMMV with FreePascal.

Comment: You're right about the **T** being odd. I must change that in the future.

Comment: What do you say about the new code? You can see that it's a Dweetta issue here ;)

Comment: Works for new code too.  I use it all the time.  You can replace the integers with enumerated types no problem.

Comment: Looks like I had the wrong mode in FPC and that's why it wasn't working for me.

Answer (score 4):

In old day pascal/delphi when you wrote:

```
const 
  A : Integer = 5;
```

You did not define a constant, but an initialized variable.

You can define without problem:

```
const
  A : array [1..2] of string = ('a', 'b');
```

But the strings have to be constants too. They need to be known at compile time.

The same goes for:

```
var
  A : array [1..2] of string = ('a', 'b');
```

So you can't write:

```
var
  B : string = 'hi';
  A : array [1..2] of string = (B, 'b');
```

Because B is a var. But you can write:

```
const
  B = 'hi'; // Even a typed constant does not work.

var
  A : array [1..2] of string = (B, 'b');
```

Note that the option: "Assignable typed constants" (default false) is provided to create the old time typed constants that can be assigned. It is just there for backwards compatibility, because you really want your constants to be constant.

Comment: You still do, if {$J+} is set.

Comment: Yes that's similar to enable assignable typed constants (atc's). But you could argue if it's good to do that ;-).